How to concat LocalDate and Time on JPQL with java version 21 and Spring boot 3.0
I using code look like and it working on spring boot 2.0 and JDK 8
But when i update into spring boot 3.0 and JDK 21 it throw me error when concat date and time
Query :
queryString.append(" ORDER BY COALESCE(b.someDATE, b.date + b.time) DESC, b.updateDate ")

It throw me error :
Operand of + is of type 'java.time.LocalTime' which is not a temporal amount (it is not an instance of 'java.time.TemporalAmount')

It working success on Spring boot 3.0 and JDK 8 but error on spring boot 3.0 and JDK 21.
I try use :
ORDER BY COALESCE(b.someDATE, TIMESTAMP(b.date + b.time))

But it not working. Please help
